# failed to create deliver client for orderer: hyprledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have a problem with installing Hyperledger Fabric.

`Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7050: connect: connection refused"`

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the similar issue and i resolved it by applying below changes in docker-compose yaml files

changed networks to this

```
networks:      
  fabric_test:
```

Replaced

```
1. image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
2. image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest  
3. image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
```

TO

1. image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.2
2. image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2
3. image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.2

Run ./network.sh down and then ./network.sh up createChannel -ca -s couchdb

Comment: How does this solve the issue? Is there a networking misconfiguration in the latest version of those images?